# Appropriate exception to throw when a parsing error occurs?

Tags: java, parsing, exception

When parsing a custom (text) file format in Java, what is the appropriate exception to throw when a syntax error is encountered? I'm looking for something analogous to .NET's [FormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx).

---

Edit: The part about parsing might be slightly misleading. What I'm doing is not so much parsing as reading a line from a file, passing it to a method that extracts colon-separated fields from it, hence why I thought FormatException would be appropriate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`java.text.ParseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html) seems the most appropriate. If you want a runtime exception and not a checked one, `IllegalArgumentException` is probably the most appropriate.